# Flask exceedingly slow to query MongoLab

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, mlab

I have Mongolab database containing a collection on small timeseries documents.

Each document contain a slice of a specific timeseries (250 daily price values for a specific stock in each document). The collection is indexed on the query field.

I need to query all slices linked to one specific stock, like this:

```
cursor = db.timeseries.find({'stock':'IBM'})    # this line executes in very small time
slices = [slice for slice in cursor]            # this line takes 10 seconds

# to give an idea, cursor.count() could be anywhere between 10 and 40
```

If I run this code in a python interpreter, it completes in sub 300 ms.

If I run the same code, on the same db, in Flask running on local, it takes **10 seconds** (!!!). The issue is not selecting the data with `find()`, which works fine, but rather querying all the data back.

Noticeably, if I connect the local Flask app to **a local mongodb, it runs fine**.

I have not found a similar Flask-specific issue mentioned online. Any clues?

Comment: Are you specifying a host name? Or an IP address?

Comment: At the start of the app I specify `app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@dsxxxxxx.mongolab.com:55802/<dbname>'`

Comment: It may be a DNS lookup issue. Try connecting to an IP instead of a host name, for example `50.19.86.168` instead of `dsxxxxxx.mongolab.com`. Resolving the IP can take a long time.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. See below for the way I solved it, could the issue in flask-pymongo be linked?

Comment: Strange. Try the slow code with a fixed IP and see if that helps.

Comment: Mongolab said they cannot provide a fixed IP. I somehow worked around it by improving the indexing in a data-specific way, as detailed in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486038/what-is-fastest-structure-to-read-in-mongodb-multiple-documents-or-subdocuments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in a somewhat naive way:

Instead of relying on [Flask-PyMongo](https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.org/), I simply used plain [pymongo](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) in the flask app as you would normally, and it works very quickly:

**Fast - pymongo version**

```
# use pymongo in a classic way

mongolab_uri = 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@dsxxxxxx.mongolab.com:55802/<dbname>'
connection = pymongo.MongoClient(host=mongolab_uri)        
db = connection['<dbname>']
coll = db.<collection_name>

# from here query and do whatever you need to
```

**Slow - Flask-Pymongo version**

```
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb:...'
mongo = PyMongo(app)
coll = mongo.db.<collection_name>
```

Comment: did you ever understand why this happened?

Comment: Not really, I redid the proof of concept with pymongo and it worked fine