# What is fastest structure to read in MongoDB: multiple documents or subdocuments?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

**Intro**

I use Mongo to store moderately long financial timeseries, which I can read in 2 ways:

- retrieve 1 series for its entire length
- retrieve N series on a specific date

To facilitate the second type of query, I slice the series by year. This reduces the data load when querying for large number of series on a specific day (example: if I query the value of 1000 timeseries on a specific day, it is not feasible to query back the entire history of each, which can go back 40 years = 28k each)

**Question**

Writes are not time-sensitive. Storage space is plentiful. **Reads are time-sensitive**. What is the best option to archive data for **fast reads** of both first and second kind?

***Option A - Separate documents***

```
{_id:xxx, stock:IBM, year:2014, prices:[<daily prices for 2014>]}
{_id:xxx, stock:IBM, year:2015, prices:[<daily prices for 2015>]}
```

In option A, I would `find()` with a compound index on `year` and `stock`

***Option B - Sub-documents***

```
{
 _id:xxx,
 stock:IBM,
 2014:[<daily prices for 2014>],
 2015:[<daily prices for 2015>],
 }
```

In option B, I would `find()` on a simple index on `stock`, and add a projection to only return the `year` I look for

***Option B.1 - Sub-documents with zipped content***

Same as above, but the `<daily prices for 201x>` are zipped by jsoning and zlibbing them

***Option C - Sub-documents with daily data***

```
{
 _id:xxx,
 stock:IBM,
     0:<price for day 0 of 2014>,
     1:<price for day 1 of 2014>,
     ...
     n:<price for day n of 2015>,  //n can be as large as 10.000
 }
```

***Option D - Nested Sub-documents***

```
{
 _id:xxx,
 stock:IBM,
 2014:{
     0:<price for day 0>,
     1:<price for day 1>,
     ...
     }
 2015:{
     0:<price for day 0>,
     1:<price for day 1>,
     ...
     }
```

I would then have to apply a query approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982285/mongodb-projection-of-nested-arrays). To note that option D might double the data required to do a read of the first type described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I think I can improve your model to be easier:

```js
{
  _id: new ObjectId()
  key: "IBM",
  date: someISODate,
  price: somePrice,
  exchange: "NASDAQ"
}
db.stocks.createIndex({key:1, date:1, exchange:1})
```

In this model, you have all the information you need:

```js
db.stocks.find({
  key: "IBM", 
  date: { 
    $gte: new ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    $lt: new ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00Z")
  }
})
```

For example, if you wanted to know the average price of the IBM stock in May 2014, you'd use an aggregation:

```js
db.stocks.aggregate([
  { $match: {
      key: "IBM",
      date:{
        $gte: new ISODate("2014-05-01T00:00:00Z"),
        $lt: new ISODate("2014-06-01T00:00:00Z")
      }
  },
  { $group: {
      _id: {
        stock: "$key",
        month: { $month:"$date"},
        year: { $year:"$date" }
      },
      avgPrice: {$avg: "$price" }
    }
  }
]}
```

Would result in a returned document like:

```js
{
  _id: {
    stock: "IBM",
    year: "2014",
    month: "5"
  },
  avgPrice: "8000.42"
}
```

You could even precalculate the averages for every stock and every month rather easily

```js
db.stocks.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
        _id: {
          stock: "$key",
          month: { $month: "$date" },
          year: { $year: "$date" }
        },
        averagePrice: {$avg:"$price"}
    }
  },
  { $out: "avgPerMonth" }
]}
```

finding the average for IBM in May 2014 now becomes a simple query:

```js
db.avgPerMonth.find({
   "_id":{
     "stock":"IBM",
     "month":"5",
     "year":"2014"
   }
})
```

And so on. You really want to use aggregations with stocks. For example: "In which month of the year was the IBM stock most expensive historically?"

Nice, easy, with optimum performance for both reads and writes.
Also, you save multiple [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) statements (for arbitrary keys that's not too easy, anyway) for the aggregation queries, too.

Granted, we have the redundancy of the duplicate values for `key`, but we circumvent a few problems:

1. [BSON documents are limited to a size of 16MB](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size), so your model would impose a theoretical limit.
2. When using the mmapv1 storage engine of MongoDB (which is the only one available for MongoDB < 3.0 and default for > 3.0), expanding the size of documents may result in a rather expensive document migration within a data file, since documents are guaranteed to never be fragemented.
3. Complicated models lead to complicated code. Complicated code is harder to maintain. The harder code is to maintain, the longer it takes. The longer you need for a task, the more expensive (money wise and/or time wise) code maintenance becomes. Conclusion: Complicated models are more expensive than easy ones.

### *Edit*

For the dates, you need to make sure that you keep in mind the different time zones and either normalize them to Zulu Time stay within the time zone of an exchange when doing aggregations to be precise as of dates.

Comment: Markus, first off thank you very much for the articulate answer. Secondly: you propose a "one document per day" model and then index it by `{key:1, date:1, exchange:1}`, which is good for queries that focus on one stock. If I need to query **100 stocks on one single day**, should I  create a new index with inverse order `{date:1, key:1}`, or can I just `find` using an `$in` for the list of 100 stock keys? Once again, the key here is **speed of reads** (writes are not time sensitive)

Comment: Further comment: added a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508023/mongodb-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-the-latest-value-as-of-a-given-date) to build on your "one-doc-per-day" solution

Comment: Your query would be `db.stocks.find({key:{$in: keysToFind}, day:{$gte: todayStart, $lt: tomorrowStart}})`. Hence, the order of the proposed index is obeyed. That way, the documents are identified using the index only. If you really want to have blazing read performance and you are willing to invest into RAM, create an index over `{key:1, date:1, price:1, exchange:1}`, making each and every [query covered](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/query-optimization/#covered-query)(when setting `{_id:0, key:1, date:1, price:1, exchange:1}` as projection).

Comment: Further note for the archives: the covered query cannot be used for Option A above, because that option has fields which include arrays, which apparently is not permitted. Same applies to any other option in the original post that contains arrays.

Comment: To note that this "one-doc-per-day" approach has large index sizes obviously. I have 40k time series, with 20 years of data each. That means the index size is ~5-10 gigs according to this SO post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607637/are-there-any-tools-to-estimate-index-size-in-mongodb, which increases RAM and pricing estimates somewhat.

Comment: @Pythonic But, as you have to admit, it is fast ;) 20 years of data for 40k stocks and *just* 10Gigs is a good deal in my book. ;)

Comment: Yes agree, the speed-ram compromise is impressive, Any suggestion on how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508023/mongodb-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-the-latest-value-as-of-a-given-date ?

Answer (score 0):

Current solution:

I have found this approach based on **Option A** to be quite performing, for both kind of reads described above:

```
cursor = mycollection.find({'year':{ '$in': years}, 'stocks':{ '$in': stocks }}).hint('year_1_ind_1')

docs = [d for d in docs]
```