# MongoDB - What is the fastest way to get the latest value as-of a given date?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of measurements from different sources, which come at different frequencies.

How do I get the **latest good value as-of a specific date**, for any given subset of sources? (this is similar to [pandas.Index.asof](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.Index.asof.html))?

To be clear, for some of these timeseries **there might be no available value for the desired date**, so I must find the most recent among the available dates that are lower than the query date.

The timeseries could look like this:

```
{_id:new ObjectId(), source:"1stDayofMonth", date:new ISODate(<day1>) value:somevalue}
{_id:new ObjectId(), source:"Monday", date:new ISODate(<day1>) value:somevalue}
{_id:new ObjectId(), source:"daily", date:new ISODate(<day1>) value:somevalue}
/...
{_id:new ObjectId(), source:"daily", date:new ISODate(<dayN>) value:somevalue}
{_id:new ObjectId(), source:"Wednesday", date:new ISODate(<dayN>) value:somevalue}
// and so on...
```

Given proper indexation (`db.myCollection.createIndex({date:1, source:1})`), how can I get the latest good `value` as-of a given `queryDate`, for any subset of `sources`?

This is how far I got, but this solution fails to return just 1 `value` per `source` (if you read the code, you'll see this would work when querying on just one `source`, but when querying on different ones it returns more than 1 value of the high frequency sources):

```
querySources = ['1stDayofMonth','Monday']    # as an example, let's say I want only these 2 sources
nSources = np.size(querySources)
cursor = db.myCollection.find( {'source':{ '$in': querySources}, 'date':{ '$lt': queryDate}}).sort(date:-1).limit(nSources)
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I should have mentioned that the docs point out to [this solution](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/), but `aggregate` might be very slow and the collection large enough that query times become long (say query 1000 sources, each with 10000 days of data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting more than one result because `nSources` size is larger than 1.

You have to use `aggregate` if you want to group by the sources or you have to run one `find()` per source then join the results.

Solution using `aggregate`:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{$match : {source: {$in: ["1stDayofMonth", "Monday"]}}},
{$match : {date: {$lt: queryDate}}},
{$sort : { date : -1 } },
{$group : {
    _id : "$source",
    date : {"$first" : "$date"},
    value : {"$first" : "$value"}   
    }}
])
```

Solution using `find()`:

```
curs1 = db.myCollection.find( {'source': "1stDayofMonth", 
'date':{ '$lt': queryDate}})
.sort({date:-1}).limit(1);

curs2 = db.myCollection.find( {'source': "Monday", 
'date':{ '$lt': queryDate}})
.sort({date:-1}).limit(1);

# Now add the result from each cursor to an Array in your app
```

Comment: Thanks, nSources is there because I want to get one answer **per each member** of the querySources list

Comment: That's what I thought. It doesn't work like that. You're essentially saying "limit all the records on the size of querySources" because your .find() isn't capable of grouping on the $in statement.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are correct. I was hoping to do 1 find only to speed things up and avoid aggregate, however this will not work until I add some other ranking field on which to sort. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For the records, I found a way do covered finds by adding 1 more field to the document:

If I add a "nextDate" field to each document, which contains the date of the next sequential document for that series, then I can do a covered query for max speed:

```
find( {'ind':{$in:[<sources>]},'date':{'$lte':queryDate}, 'nextDate':{'$gt':queryDate}},
      {'_id':0, 'nextDate':0} ).hint('my_index')
```

`myindex` is built on `ind`, `date`, `nextDate`, `value`

Space & memory intensive, very fast